# Printed lines are not parallel to the paper's edge Canon i-SENSYS MF635Cx (laser printer)

Tags: laser-printer

I have this new laser printer. Of course I have an issue from the start.

The lines are not parallel to the edges, more than 1mm difference from top to bottom.

Any ideas?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3Gpw.jpg]

Comment: 1mm is probably well within tolerance. Are you sure that your paper is well aligned when being fed in?

Comment: it happens from the tray and manual feed. I trying to do a firmware update now.

Comment: Presumably if it's new, it's still under warranty. Take it up with the supplier/manufacturer.

Comment: Not sure where you are, user, but in the US almost any retail outlet will have a no-questions-asked return policy. Take it back and ask for a replacement. If the replacement has the same issue, try a different model.

Comment: It was bought over internet, I have 15 days to return it if I want.